# A Function Contains FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the scenario:

1. Checkboxlist appears when selectedindex of Radiobuttonlist=0
2. Checkboxlist has X items. User may select Y items (Y < X)
3. If Y = X (i mean if user checks all items) make Checkboxlist disappear, and make selectedindex=1 of Radiobuttonlist

This is an easy operation indeed. But i have 10 Checkboxlist/Radiobuttonlist couples. So i created the codes below:

```
protected void cblAlcohol_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//I call the function with ID of Checkboxlist/Radiobuttonlist couple
BlaBla("rblAlcohol","cblAlcohol");
}

private void BlaBla(string rblID, string cblID)
{
RadioButtonList rbl;
CheckBoxList cbl;

foreach (Control ctrl in this.Page.Controls)
{
rbl = (RadioButtonList)FindControl(rblID);
cbl = (CheckBoxList)FindControl(cblID);
}

int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < **cbl**.Items.Count; i++)
{
if (cbl.Items[i].Selected) counter++;
}

if (counter == cbl.Items.Count)
{
cbl.SelectedIndex = -1;
cbl.Visible = false;
**rbl**.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
}
```

Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'cbl' (marked as bold)

Error 2 Use of unassigned local variable 'rbl' (marked as bold)

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAlcohol" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblAlcohol_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblAlcohol" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cblAlcohol_SelectedIndexChanged"> <asp:ListItem>Maybe</asp:ListItem>                                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I couldnt get what the problem is.

Thankss in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `foreach` line in:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Page.Controls)
{
  rbl = (RadioButtonList)FindControl(rblID);
  cbl = (CheckBoxList)FindControl(cblID);
}
```

You are executing exactly the same code as many times as there are controls in `this.Page`.

And unless the `checkoxlist` and `radiobuttonlist` are dynamic, you already have their references as page class members. No need to search for them with `FindControl`, simply pass the references to `BlaBla`:

```
protected void cblAlcohol_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //I call the function with ID of Checkboxlist/Radiobuttonlist couple
  BlaBla(rblAlcohol, cblAlcohol);
}

private void BlaBla(RadioButtonList rbl, CheckBoxList cbl)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler doesn't know if there will be items to iterate over in the `foreach (Control ctrl in this.Page.Controls)` (maybe there aren't any controls for example), it demands you to give a default value for `cbl` and `rbl`:

```
RadioButtonList rbl = null;
CheckBoxList cbl = null;
```

Make sure to check for `null` after the loop to avoid `NullReferenceException`s.

**Also, that `foreach` doesn't seem to be useful in any way. Just remove it.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't *know* that rbl and cbl will be assigned to here, ie. it's logically possible that they won't be:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Page.Controls)
{
    rbl = (RadioButtonList)FindControl(rblID);
    cbl = (CheckBoxList)FindControl(cblID);
}
```

Just change the lines where you declare them to:

```
RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
CheckBoxList cbl = new CheckBoxList();
```

Comment: I would never assign them with `new RadioButtonList()`... Those controls get lost after executing this code.